# jQuery add class to div while removing it from others

Tags: jquery, css

Hello I am trying to make a navigation constructed from DIV's which uses jQuery AJAX function to load pages.

The thing I want to is is when user clicks say on Pages then Dashboard or what ever active page they are on has class called active removed and added to the new clicked one

```
<div class="dijit active" id="dijit_dashboard">Dashboard</div> 
<div class="dijit" id="dijit_pages">Pages</div>
```

jQuery code which doesn't quite do the work.

```
$("#dijit_pages").click(function() { 
    $("#dijit_utm").load('index.html'); 
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

but I am not sure how to remove class active from all others.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $(".dijit").live("click", function() {
        $(".dijit").removeClass("active");  // remove active class from all
        $(this).addClass("active");         // add active class to clicked element
        $("#dijit_utm").load('index.html'); 
    });
});
```

Using this method will mean the same page is loaded for each link. If you need to load a page per item, then the following code will be more apt:

```html
<div class="dijit active" id="dijit_dashboard"><a href="dashboard.html">Dashboard</a></div> 
<div class="dijit" id="dijit_pages"><a href="pages.html">Pages</a></div>
```

```js
$(function() {
    $(".dijit").live("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".dijit").removeClass("active");  // remove active class from all
        $(this).addClass("active");         // add active class to clicked element
        var href = $(this).find("A").attr("href");
        $("#dijit_utm").load(href);
    });
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

This old answer still seems to get quite steady views, so here's an updated answer using the latest jQuery methods as `live()` has been deprecated since version 1.7:

```
$(document).on('click', '.dijit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $el = $(this);
    $el.addClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active');
    $("#dijit_utm").load($el.find('a').attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: I'm using the updated answer on my WordPress site to start some CSS animations. However what do I need to add to this code to be able to click on the active div and remove the class from it?

Comment: Perhaps `$(document).on('click', '.active', e => $(e.target).removeClass('active'));` but this is just a guess without seeing your code. If you're having issues I'd suggest starting your own question, including all relevant code.

Comment: Thanks Rory, I've posted a new question with my code so hopefully it's an easy answer!

Comment: It was! Just change addClass to toggleClass should've worked that out earlier!

Answer (score 3):

I added a line to your code which finds all `DIV` elements with the `active` class and removes that class:

```
$( '#dijit_pages' ).click( function()
{
  $( '#dijit_utm' ).load( 'index.html' );
  $( 'div.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );
  $( this ).addClass( 'active' );
} );
```

It may be too broad for your purposes, though, if you're using the active class in places other than your menu. If that's that case, you want to narrow the scope of where the selction for elements with class `active` searches.

**Edit:** With your added markup, I would change to this:

```
$( function()
{
  var $dijitMenuItems = $( '.digit' ),
      activeClass = 'active';

  $dijitMenuItems.click( function( e )
  {
    $( '#dijit_utm' ).load( 'index.html' ); //will need more info to determine how to find href to load
    $dijitMenuItems.removeClass( activeClass );
    $( this ).addClass( activeClass );

    e.preventDefault(); //most likely needed to stop any link-following from within the DIV
  } );
} );
```

Comment: I could try using variables to pull the data