# Add function to remove class from current item on click

Tags: jquery

I'm using some jQuery on my WordPress site to start some CSS animations within an SVG image (got the code from the updated accepted answer from this question) [jQuery add class to div while removing it from others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820977/jquery-add-class-to-div-while-removing-it-from-others/5821013?noredirect=1#comment117667255_5821013). However what do I need to add to this code to be able to click on the active div and remove the class from it? At the moment everything is working but I'd like to also be able to click on the active item and have the class removed. Code is below.

```
$(document).on('click', '#timeline g', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var $el = $(this);
$el.addClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active'); });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found a simple solution, just change the addClass to toggleClass

```
$(document).on('click', '#timeline g', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var $el = $(this);
$el.toggleClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active'); 
});
```